# CSS Transition while moving an element from a div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery's html() to move around an element. Please see the example below.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
//on some event (for example, onclick, onmouseover, onkeydown....), the code below will be triggered
var $myDiv = $("#myDiv");
$("#div1").html($myDiv);
//after some other event, the code below will be triggered
$("#div5").html($myDiv);
//after some other event, the code below will be triggered
$("#div4").html($myDiv);
//etc....
```

Basically, I am trying to move $myDiv among div1-5 using the method html() above.
But I want to have transition too when $myDiv moves from one div to another div
I tried the following css but it didn't work.
CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

I don't know the size of all the divs and the size might change, so I can't really use transition on top and left.

Hope someone can have a good solution.

Thanks

Comment: You're not "moving" `#myDiv` with `html()`, you're injecting it. If you want to apply a transition on move, one option could be to use absolute positioning and transition on the `left` or `top` property, but without knowing exactly what you're doing, I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin.

You can give each draggable `div` an in of `sortable`, then use the following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Remember you will need to include jQuery UI:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```